# How to add space at the borders of gantt chart?

Tags: spacing, pgfgantt

I created a Gantt chart and I want to add some space (Like the space at red arrows)so that there is no chart arrows outside the borders?

Is there anyway to do that?!

thanks

[image: Current Gantt Chart]

```
\begin{ganttchart}[
vgrid
]{1}{16}
\gantttitle{Weeks}{16} \\
\gantttitlecalendar{day} \\[grid]

\ganttgroup{Phase 1}{1}{5} \\
\ganttbar{System Analysis}{1}{3} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{System Design}{4}{5} \ganttnewline
\ganttmilestone{System Architecture}{5} \ganttnewline

\ganttgroup{Phase 3}{6}{13} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{System Implementation}{6}{8} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Benchmarks Implementation}{9}{12} \ganttnewline
\ganttmilestone{System and Benchmarks code}{12} \ganttnewline

\ganttgroup{Phase 4}{13}{13} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{System Evaluation}{13}{13} \ganttnewline
\ganttmilestone{Evaluation Results}{13} \ganttnewline

\ganttgroup{Phase 4}{14}{16} \\
\ganttbar{Documentation}{14}{16}\ganttnewline
\ganttmilestone{Milestone}{16} 

\ganttlink{elem1}{elem2}
\ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
\ganttlink{elem3}{elem4}
\ganttlink{elem4}{elem5}
\ganttlink{elem5}{elem6}
\ganttlink{elem6}{elem7}
\ganttlink{elem7}{elem8}
\ganttlink{elem8}{elem9}
\ganttlink{elem9}{elem10}
\ganttlink{elem10}{elem11}
\ganttlink{elem11}{elem12}
\ganttlink{elem12}{elem13}

\end{ganttchart}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the chart go from `{0}` to `{17}` and adjust the title and calendar title accordingly. For the `\calendartitle` you need to use the starred version which allows you to specify the range, and add offset options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
vgrid
]{0}{17}
\gantttitle{Weeks}{18} \\
\gantttitlecalendar*[title left shift=1,title right shift=1]{1}{16}{day}
 \\[grid]

\ganttgroup{Phase 1}{1}{5} \\
\ganttbar{System Analysis}{1}{3} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{System Design}{4}{5} \ganttnewline
\ganttmilestone{System Architecture}{5} \ganttnewline

\ganttgroup{Phase 3}{6}{13} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{System Implementation}{6}{8} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Benchmarks Implementation}{9}{12} \ganttnewline
\ganttmilestone{System and Benchmarks code}{12} \ganttnewline

\ganttgroup{Phase 4}{13}{13} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{System Evaluation}{13}{13} \ganttnewline
\ganttmilestone{Evaluation Results}{13} \ganttnewline

\ganttgroup{Phase 4}{14}{16} \\
\ganttbar{Documentation}{14}{16}\ganttnewline
\ganttmilestone{Milestone}{16} 

\ganttlink{elem1}{elem2}
\ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
\ganttlink{elem3}{elem4}
\ganttlink{elem4}{elem5}
\ganttlink{elem5}{elem6}
\ganttlink{elem6}{elem7}
\ganttlink{elem7}{elem8}
\ganttlink{elem8}{elem9}
\ganttlink{elem9}{elem10}
\ganttlink{elem10}{elem11}
\ganttlink{elem11}{elem12}
\ganttlink{elem12}{elem13}

\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]